# Android Studio Partially Broken

Tags: android

I downloaded Studio 3.1 and it seemed fine for a while, but now there is no "Android" view--I can only see folders under "Project" view. Also, there is no emulation and it fails to connect with any phone that is USBed to the computer. Also, there are no "SDK Options" or "Android" under the Tools menu, and most of the options under the Run menu are unclickable. I've tried invalidate caches/restart, reinstalling the program, reopening project, and nothing seems to work. Any idea what I should do? If anyone can help me, I owe you a funny joke. Thanks!

Comment: Well. Maybe you can back up your project files, remove completely android studio and then install from this link? https://developer.android.com/studio/

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I tried that and no luck. And I know a guy who did that and had no problems.

Comment: Seriously, 32 views and no ideas? Don't you want to know my funny joke?

Comment: Got it now. Some files were missing from the project.